# property assignment expected

Tags: javascript, python, html

I was trying to creat a website with following a video. But at the end i got an issue. i tried write it like " ({ note,id })" and erors gone but in my website when i tried to delete the note it doesn't work anymore. I can't see where is the problem the problem.

```html
{% extends "base.html" %} {% block title %}Home{% endblock %} {% block content
  %}
  <h1 align="center">Notes</h1>
  <ul class="list-group list-group-flush" id="notes">
    {% for note in user.notes %}
    <li class="list-group-item">
      {{ note.data }}
      <button type="button" class="close" onClick="deleteNote({{ note.id }})">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
  <form method="POST">
    <textarea name="note" id="note" class="form-control"></textarea>
    <br />
    <div align="center">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Note</button>
    </div>
  </form>
  {% endblock %}
```

and this is my js code.

```js
function deleteNote(noteId) {
    fetch("/delete-note", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({ noteId: noteId }),
    }).then((_res) => {
      window.location.href = "/";
    });
  }
```

these are my error messages.

```html
[{
    "resource": "/c:/flaskweb/website/templates/home.html",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#1",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Property assignment expected.",
    "source": "javascript",
    "startLineNumber": 8,
    "startColumn": 64,
    "endLineNumber": 8,
    "endColumn": 65
}]
```

```html
[{
    "resource": "/c:/flaskweb/website/templates/home.html",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#1",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "',' expected.",
    "source": "javascript",
    "startLineNumber": 8,
    "startColumn": 70,
    "endLineNumber": 8,
    "endColumn": 71
}]
```

```html
[{
    "resource": "/c:/flaskweb/website/templates/home.html",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#1",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "',' expected.",
    "source": "javascript",
    "startLineNumber": 8,
    "startColumn": 75,
    "endLineNumber": 8,
    "endColumn": 76
}]
```

Comment: What is producing this error message format?  Are you getting JavaScript errors in the browser?  Which line of JavaScript code does any given error refer to?

Comment: Don't you need to quote that name, since it's the same as a variable?  `body: JSON.stringify({ "noteId": noteId }),`

Comment: @TimRoberts The key part of an object literal is a literal, not a variable. You have to write `[noteId]` to make it an evaluated expression.

Comment: the error is right here "<button type="button" class="close" onClick="deleteNote({{ note.id }})">"  it says "property assignment expected" and " ',' expected" with pointing the brackets.